# Change browser URI without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, uri

How do I change the browser URL (or URI) without a page refresh using HTML5 and HTML5Shiv for IE? For instance if I am on the page http://www.example.com and I want to go to http://www.example.com/4f6gt without having to reload the page. I understand how to load the content with AJAX, I have been using AJAX for a while now, but I am new to the HTML5 point of view for this. The reason I wanna do this is because I wanna be able to have people navigate pages without the time it takes to reload the DOM of the main page, but have a deep link that they can also go to so they have a one step way to get back. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`pjax`](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) or [`history.js`](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)

It's not going to work in < IE9, because IE doesn't support html5 history api (**history.pushState()** and **history.replaceState()**). The shim won't help. Should work in IE10.

Both those plugins degrade gracefully. History.js can also degrade with a hashbang to support dynamic content loads.